# proxy url in html to render images

Tags: http, https, proxy, http-proxy, mixed-content

I am rendering http content on a https page, therefore getting the `mixed-content` error. I have searched on web what solutions there are for this issue and for now I have chosen to create a proxy server that uses https and will forward the request. If you know a better way except not using http let me know. I am not using https because I cannot change that system.

I am rendering images on my website this way.

```
<img src="http://image.com/image/12" />
```

I am wondering if it is possible to use the proxy inside `src` attribute. Something like

```
<img src="https://someproxy.com/http://image.com/image/12" />
```

I am using `django` and I could also try to make the request in python and send the image to the dom. But since I have already configured the proxy I want to try using it inside src attribute.